# Stack Overflow question resolved in Chat discussion

Tags: support, stack-overflow, chat

I have added a comment on a Stack Overflow question and the OP offers *"Move this discussion to chat"* and we have discussed his issue in chat. And I have resolved his issue.

Can I reform the chat discussion and post it as an answer?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ : The Stackoverflow question not mine. I have resolved in the chat

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood. Sure you can write an answer based on your discussion. What do you think is the problem?

Comment: I am just thinking because OP did to many wrong thing in his code  we have corrected one by one. It is correct to mention all the steps and post as a answer ?

Comment: Maybe the question is _off-topic_ at all. But that shouldn't affect your answer primarily.

Comment: Would be nice to see the concrete example.

Answer (score 5):

> Can I reform the chat discussion and post it as an answer?

Sure you can do that.

> [From comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/323135/stack-overflow-question-resolved-in-chat-discussion#comment1056632_323135): I am just thinking because OP did to many wrong thing in his code we have corrected one by one. It is correct to mention all the steps and post as a answer ?

Well, one can argue ins such case that the OP's question was *off-topic* because of being *too-broad* or *unclear* at all.

But generally that shouldn't affect you giving an answer how to fix all their mistakes.

On the other hand at least at Stack Overflow, there's a close reason for questions asking about *simple or typographical* errors, and that question would be closed and deleted in the longer terms anyways.

It's your choice if you think it's worth the effort, and you believe that Q&A pair would be useful for future research, or better flag the question for closure<sup>1</sup>.

---

<sup>1)</sup><sub>Note that answered *off-topic* questions makes it harder, and takes more effort to remove them.</sub>